# Override/remove XML Config node/value?

Tags: overrides, configuration

I want to remove some XML value without touching core XML files, is it possible ?

The scenario is the following.

In `/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/etc/config.xml` we have some config value for the totals (`<sales><quote><totals>`).
I want to comment out the `tax` one so the tax line is not displayed in the frontend.

- commenting the node in the core XML file works fine but it is not the best approach.
- If I have put new empy values in a separate module I have a different effect ( it is not like remove the declaration)

In particular I want to do something like:

- `<!--<renderer>tax/checkout_tax</renderer>-->`

Comment: Is there some reason you can't change the settings under `System > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings` to not show tax?

Comment: it is not exactly the same ... however thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically inside of your module you can:

1. in `config.xml` reset the node to something like `<renderer>0</renderer>`
2. register an observer and `Mage::getConfig()->setNode('path', NULL)`

Comment: `<renderer>0</renderer>` is giving me a different result: removing the node from core XML file return `null` while `<renderer>0</renderer>` return a string with value 0

Comment: Try putting `null` instead of `0`. If it will not work try option 2.

Comment: I have already tried both ( 0 and null ) the issue is that they are converted to string ... I think solution 2 is the only one working

Comment: @Francesco, not quite. Solution 1 can be still valid for some cases where setting the value to `0` or something else will do the job.

Comment: Hi Tim, I think it is good idea to improve the answer specifying that `method 1` is not equivalent to comment out the line in the core file

Comment: `removeNode()` is not a valid method

Comment: yes, you're right. fixed.

Comment: Hi Tim, what event is the one to be observed? I am looking in app/code/Core/Model/Config.php and I can't see any event of interest

Comment: Try `controller_front_init_before`.